Can I get very high current (1000s of amps) using multi stage op amps?
If I wanted to build a power supply that could output 1000s of amps at low adjustable voltages, could I do this by using multi-stage op amps? Is this the best way to build a high current adjustable voltage power supply?

@All - Even if the answer is simple, please don't answer in a comment. That is not one of the allowed uses of comments  (please see here for why answering in a comment can be harmful & here for more details of the allowed uses of comments). TY

An op-amp cannot supply more current than is applied to its power pins. So, unless you already have a power supply that can provide 1000s of amps, an op-amp (or many) won't help you.
If you want a source of 1000s of amps, your options include transformers and switching power supplies. Both can take a higher voltage source and convert to a lower voltage with more current. Procuring or building such a power supply would be difficult and expensive.
If you need an adjustable supply, you almost certainly should use a (synchronously rectified) switching regulator. Using linear regulation techniques for thousands of amps will generate huge amounts of heat.

Thanks for the answer. We have a vendor that we have been buying them from but I was wondering if we could make our own. The tricky thing is that the voltage needs to be adjustable/programmable. Which is why I was thinking an adjustable voltage regulator and amplifying the heck out of the output.

Please post a link to the supply you are using now.

No, you would use an op-amp to control the voltage and limit current like this. Below is a 14-volt 30 amp DC power supply with precision voltage and current control. The current is limited to 30 amps and will voltage fold back to 5 amps if overloaded. I used R11 as the variable load. The op-amps control the pass elements M1, Q1, and Q2.


While your circuit does demonstrate the basic concept of a linear supply, I think you've grossly overestimated the capabilities of those pass transistors.

Duly noted, a fat finger typo. 2N5886 will easily do 50 amps

Well, actually two of them won't easily do 50A, that would be running them at their absolute maximum ratings. Rule of thumb for linear regulated supplies, one pass transistor for every 5A of current. That's if you're building one yourself, commercial ones typically use one transistor per 8A to save money. I would use 6 x TIP35C for a 30A supply.


If I wanted to build a power supply that could output 1000s of amps at low adjustable voltages, could I do this by using multi-stage op amps?

Yes.

Is this the best way to build a high current adjustable voltage power supply?

No, because this would waste kilowatts of power.  You would be litterly burning money to pay for the electricity that's heating the opamps, which would then require more wasted $$$ to install heat management systems to transport said heat away from said opamps to save them from burning up.
The best way to do this is by using switch-mode power converters.  To help you further, please specify the output voltage range, the input power source, and the application.
